# Merging a splitted .ts recorded by dvb reciever that uses fat32 file system without losing frames

Tags: video, video-editing, video-encoding, dvb-t

My receiver uses fat32 file system which limits a single .ts file to 3.99 gb ~4gb which is equivalent to a certain duration depending on the recorded channel. If it's done recording the allowed 4 gb, it will create a new file. The problem is that there are some frames lost between the two files.

Also sometimes the duration of the second file is messed up.

My dvb receiver is a cheap one (although there are better receivers that do this split thing) with little options so i guess solving the problem from there would be impossible

How to merge these two files into a single one without losing frames?

Comment: Perhaps better to use a better file system. Hard to believe your device supports FAT only.

Comment: *How to merge these two files into a single one without losing frames?* The lost frames are lost, and were lost in that small time window that occurs when the system is creating the next file. No software will give something that isn't there in the first place. Again, solve the root cause, not the symptoms.